# Finding variance of infimum of a set

Tags: self-study, variance, independence, exponential-distribution

Let $X_1, X_2, \cdots,X_n$ be independent and identically distributed random variables having an exponential distribution with mean $\frac{1}{\lambda}$.

Let $S_n=X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n$ and $N = \text{inf}\left\{n \geq \ 1:S_n > 1\right\}$. Then $\operatorname{Var}(N)$ equals

1. 1
2. $\lambda$
3. $\lambda^2$
4. $\infty$

I don't understand the question and only thing I could deduce from the question is that $S_n$ has variance $\frac{n}{\lambda^2}$. Can somebody please explain what the question demands.

Comment: Have you learned Poisson process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define $N^*(t)$ as
$$
N^*(t) = \text{max}(n \mid S_n \leq t)
$$
and  $N(t)$ as
$$
N(t) = \text{min}(n \mid S_n > t)
$$
We have $N(t) = N^*(t) + 1$ and $N = N(1)$.

Since $S_n$ is a sum of $n$ iid random variables exponentially distributed (with parameter $\lambda$), $N^*(t)$ is a *Poisson process*.

For fixed $t$, $N^*(t)$ thus follows a Poisson distribution with intensity $\lambda t$ and so we have
$$
\mathbb{E}[N^*(t)] = \lambda t
$$
and,
$$
\text{var}[N^*(t)] = \lambda t
$$

Thus,
$$
\mathbb{E}[N(t)] = \lambda t +1
$$
$$
\text{var}[N(t)] = \lambda t
$$

Finally  $\mathbb{E}[N] = \mathbb{E}[N(1)]= \lambda +1$ and $\text{var}(N) = \lambda$

This result can be checked using simulations, for example assuming $\lambda=15$,

```
R=sapply(1:1000,function(i){
X<-rexp(100,15)
S<-cumsum(X) 
N<-min(which(S>1))  
return(N)})
```

The command

```
mean(R)
```

should gives something close to 16.

Comment: Can you please explain the relation, N(t)=N∗(t)+1 and N=N(1).

Comment: If $N^*(t)$ is the maximum $n$  for which $S_n$ is lower than $t$, obviously the subsequent $n$ will lead to $S_n$ to be greater than $t$. Hence $N^*(t)+1$ is the smallest $n$ for which $S_n>t$, thus $N^*(t) + 1 = N(t)$. For $N=N(1)$ just replace $t$ by 1 in the definition of $N(t)$ leads to the definition of $N$. Here inf and min share the same meaning.